# ruby on rails - Unable to load application: LoadError: cannot load such file -- database_cleaner/active_record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dev-to-production, database-cleaner, onrender

I am trying to deploy ruby on rails project on render platform. I inherited this project in my school and added new features there. I get the following error when I run my Rails application in production mode, but when I run my app in development mode it works fine.  "Unable to load application: LoadError: cannot load such file -- database_cleaner/active_record ".

I tried to follow all steps in docs https://render.com/docs/deploy-rails, reinstall cleaner gem, checked compatability, nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1. In the Gemfile, moved `database_cleaner-active_record` out of the `:development` block, so it gets installed always
2. Moved the require in the `cypress_rails` intializer to after the return statement

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

- **Gemfile**: Make sure that the **database_cleaner** gem is included in your Gemfile and that it is not limited to certain environments.
  It should be available in all environments.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  # Other gems...
end
```

- **Bundle Install**: Run **bundle install** to ensure that all the gems,
  including **database_cleaner**, are properly installed.

```
bundle install
```

- **Environment Configuration**: Check your
  **config/environments/production.rb** file or the relevant environment
  configuration file. Ensure that the **database_cleaner** gem is not
  explicitly disabled or excluded in the production environment.
- **Database Cleaner Configuration**: If you are using **database_cleaner** for
  test purposes only, make sure that it is correctly configured in your
  **spec_helper.rb** or **rails_helper.rb** file and not causing issues in the
  production environment.

  Example configuration in **rails_helper.rb**:

```
# rails_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Other configurations...

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

**Notes**: Ensure that you are using a version of database_cleaner that is compatible with your Rails version.

Comment: Thank you. Actuakky this worked for me:                                                                                               1. In the Gemfile, move database_cleaner-active_record out of the :development block, so it gets installed always
1.Moved the require in the cypress_rails intializer to after the return statement